# Can't Change Screen Order in Bottom Tab Navigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a bottom tab navigator in my app.

```
<Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen
      //...
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="BottomTab"
      component={BottomTab}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //...
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

It include 3 screens inside itself.

```
<Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
            //...
                 >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="SearchScreen"
            //...
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="HomeScreen"
            //...
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="CartScreen"
            //...
                  />
        </Tab.Navigator>
```

[image]

I've changed the initialRouteName to "HomeScreen" to see HomeScreen at first. But, if i go back after HomeScreen shows up, screen changes to SearchScreen. But i want it to go the screen that where BottomTab Stack Screen get called instead of SearchScreen when i'm in HomeScreen.

Here is the packages that i use:

"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2"

"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11"

"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2"

Comment: Is this React, or React Native? What library are you using? Or did you write those `Tab` and `Stack` components yourself?

Comment: @davidx1 This is react-native with react-native-navigation.

Comment: @davidx1 I've just realised that i didn't specify any package, i'm sorry. Here, i edited my question.